# Case-insensitive string operations in es2018

Tags: javascript, string, case-insensitive

We have multiple native methods provided by the `String` object in JavaScript:

- [`String.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)
- [`String.prototype.endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)
- [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)
- [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
- [`String.prototype.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

All of them are case-sensitive.

When it comes to case-insensitive operations, we have some popular options, though they all are far from the ideal.

### `toUpperCase()` \ `toLowerCase()`

The most popular trick is to use `toUpperCase()` \ `toLowerCase()` methods. However, they do not work properly for all languages (German, Turkish, etc.) and have a performance hit of converting both strings even though the result of an operation could be known by looking at the first pair of characters.

### `RegEx`es

The second option is to use `RegEx`es with `i` option. However, it also has two main disadvantages:

- unclear and messy code (as it's almost always the
  case with `RegEx`es)
- performance overhead caused by composing a `RegEx` string  and compiling it into an actual `RegEx` on every operation

Also, those solutions were 'invented' during the ages of ancient JavaScript VMs. Nowadays with `Intl` (and other newer) API and transpilers like TypeScript and Babel as well as polyfill libraries like `core-js`, we could easily employ the latest JavaScript APIs for any app.

What's the solution for case-insensitive `String` operations in es2018?

I'm looking for production (think MDN polyfills) quality performant i18n-friendly code which is designed to be a universal go-to solution for the problem.

Comment: Converting to upper case before doing the comparison is as good as it gets.

Comment: I think regular expressions are perfectly fine - if a coder knows regular expressions, then if the operation is *simple* (like the five string operations you listed), the resulting regex *should* be quite readable. `and compiling it into an actual RegEx on every operation` Or just use a regex literal, and not a string (don't ever use `new RegExp` unless you need to concatenate a variable)

Comment: Also, if you don't want to convert the whole string to lower/upper case before checking, you could always *slice* the string beforehand. eg instead of `'foObAR'.toLowerCase().startsWith('foo')`, do `'foObAR'.slice(0, 3).toLowerCase().startsWith('foo')`

Comment: @giorgiga before today I would have agreed with you, but it turns out that there are "unstable" Unicode code points that do not translate to lower case in a reliable way. You can write a simple test yourself: iterate through 16-bit values calling `String.fromCharCode()` and compare `.toLowerCase().toUpperCase()` to just `.toUpperCase()` and several characters fail the test!

Comment: @CertainPerformance Could you elaborate on `just use a regex literal, and not a string`? How can we use a pre-compiled literal to implement, let's say, `s1,startsWithCaseInsensitive(s2)` if we have both strings as variables?

Comment: @CertainPerformance `you could always slice the string beforehand` comment. 1. How do you define the number of characters for `slice`ing in a `startsWithCaseInsensitive()` polyfill? 2. `slice`ing means (a) memory allocation and (b) some kind of a loop for a memory area copying (even though the latter might be compiled into a single high-level CPU instruction). This optimization benefit is completely dependent on length of the string and could be an unnecessary overcomplication for a universal polyfill. At least, I've never seen such optimization-targetted case analysis in the MDN polifills.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov String slicing actually is a constant time operation without much allocation in JS, which has immutable strings. It would just create a new value backed by the same buffer (simplified).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some implementations for a case insensitive `startsWith`

Without converting the whole string to lowercase, and instead using only the length of the test string:

```
function startsWith_Insensitive(str, test) { 
    return str.substr(0, test.length).toLowerCase() === test.toLowerCase();
}
```

And I assume that it would also be more efficient to convert and test the characters one by one, and stop if any are different, instead of converting them all and then testing them, so that would look like this:

```
function startsWith_Insensitive(str, test) {
    if (str.length < test.length) return false;
    for (let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
        if (str[i].toLowerCase() !== test[i].toLowerCase()) 
            return false    
    } 
    return true    
}
```